# C#, SQLServer - block table row reading, edit if needed and release lock

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I need to block database reads on row level while I'm executing update logic for same row. How would nice and clean solution look like? Here is some code I'm working on:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.ConnectionString)) {
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable)) {
        //TODO lock table row with ID=primaryKey (block other reads and updates)
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Data FROM MyTable WHERE ID=@primaryKey", conn)) { 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@primaryKey", primaryKey);
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                data = PopulateData(reader);
            };
        }

        if (isUpdateNeeded(data)) {
            ChangeExternalSystemStateAndUpdateData(data) //EDIT - concurrent calls not allowed
            WriteUpdatesToDatabase(conn, tran, data);    //EDIT
            tran.Commit();
        }


    } //realease lock and allow other processes to read row with ID=primaryKey
}
```

### EDIT:

I have following constraints:

- Code can be executed within different App pools simultaneously. So memory lock is not an option
- ChangeExternalSystemStateAndUpdateData() must be executed only once in the scope of the MyTable row. Concurrent calls will cause problems

Comment: Rather than locking, consider using optimistic concurrency where you check to see if the row has changed during the update operation. See [Optimistic Concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/optimistic-concurrency) for more info an examples. Note that you can use a single [rowversion column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) rather than passing all the original values to detect changes.

Comment: You don't need to lock rows to edit them. This problem was solved in the 1990s by using optimistic concurrency. If you want to use database locks to emulate checkin/checkout, you **can't**. Database locks are meant to be short lived. The checkout/edit/checkin cycle is a *business* concept that takes minutes if not days. Add *explicit* checkin/checkout functionality to your application, eg with checkout flags and dates, checkout users etc. Modify your application to just *not* edit checked out records.

Comment: All POS, document management applications work that way. If they took database locks while the user tried to find a field on a form to update, they wouldn't be able to handle more than a dozen concurrent users. They wouldn't be able to handle accidental disconnections or errors either. Web applications simply wouldn't be able to do anything - you can't keep a database lock across requests.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos nobody mentioned UI systems here; now, there *is* a question over how long `ChangeExternalSystemStateAndUpdateData` is going to take - if it is excessive, then yes: optimistic concurrency may be useful for preventing blocks impacting other systems, but that is double-edged, since if you use optimistic concurrency you need to *expect* it to fail, which means you then need to be able to frequently compensate the external systems due to a failed DB update; pessimistic concurrency is much simpler and is probably the best bet if the external update isn't terribly slow

Comment: My problem with Optimistic Concurrency is that violations are checked only during update procedure - this wouldn't prevent concurrent calls to UpdateData function which I want to prevent.

Comment: @AndreTchernikov you can still do it with optimistic concurrency though - you just add a column like `LockedBy nvarchar(50) null` (and usually `LockExpiry datetime null`), and make taking a lock an explicit thing that happens *as a column in the database*, and have your code check the values when deciding what to do

Comment: ChangeExternalSystemStateAndUpdateData involves usually external API calls could take up to 20 seconds.

Comment: @AndreTchernikov hmmm; 20 seconds *is* a long time to hold a transactional lock for; in particular, note that this could impact things like lists/searches - unless those systems are configured to make sure that they bypass locks (note: this might not be necessary if they're running in the default isolation level, read-committed)

Comment: @MarcGravell In principal I'm doing a db level cache for external API calls. This method would be a single point of access to Db. So its should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the problem here isn't so much *row locking*, but rather: other SPIDs acquiring *read* locks between your read and your update - which can lead to deadlock scenarios; the common fix here is to acquire a *write* lock in the initial read:

```sql
SELECT Data FROM MyTable WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE ID=@primaryKey
```

Note that if another SPID is explicitly using `NOLOCK` then they'll still blitz past it.

You could also try adding `ROWLOCK`, i.e. `WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)` - personally I'd keep it simple initially. Since you're in a serializable context, trying to be too granular may be a lost cause - key-range locks, etc.

Comment: My main concern is that `UpdateData()` can be heavy operation and can changes state of external system. As well it could be executed within different app pools. So I cant use memory locks. Is there a way to ensure `UpdateData()` is called only once in scope of the MyTable row?

Comment: @AndreTchernikov nobody mentioned "memory locks", whatever that means; as for the rest : that is what serializable transactions with locking *do*; note: this only means that multiple attempts to do this will run *sequentially* (rather than concurrently) - whether it runs multiple times comes down to what your `isUpdateNeeded` logic does. With the code as shown, competing threads should get blocked at the `ExecuteReader` until the competitor with the conch completes (whether through commit or rollback)

Comment: MarcGravell, sorry for the memory lock confusion. UPDLOCK is bit onknown for me. So statement `SELECT Data FROM MyTable WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE ID=99` within one transaction. Will block same SQL select statement within another transaction?

Comment: @AndreTchernikov it will prevent other SPIDs from obtaining a read lock (or higher); in the case of a "serializable" isolation level, that means it'll block anything that tries to read that (whatever), since at "serializable" isolation level, read locks are taken by default (unless NOLOCK is specified); but it would block the same SQL statement **including the UPDLOCK hint** even *without* a transaction / serializable context, since you're *telling it* to try and take a lock (a write lock in this case); it can't take a read or write lock if your first SPID already has a write lock

Comment: @AndreTchernikov a shorter version of that is probably simply "yes", but: it is more nuanced and subtle than that